# Manage comunication protocol local socket c

Tags: c, sockets

I'm trying to implement my first client-server application with an AF_UNIX socket in C.

I have to respect a specific protocol of communication for the queries sent from client. Three types of queries are available:

```
1) <command_name> <object_name> <obj_len> \n <obj_data>

2) <command_name> <object_name> \n

3) <command_name> \n
```

Note that each query except the first terminate with a \n special character, and the length of each message is unknown .

I have no problem to read 2) and 3) because i know the message will ends with a \n so i just have to check if the last byte read in the buffer is \n, if not, i will continue to read from socket and append the subsequent calls to buffer.

Instead for the first operation the above method doesn't work, because the \n character is not at the end of the message but it is in an arbitrary point of the buffer.
What i would do is to read (in that case) until i reach the \n , then parse the *obj_len* token from buffer and do the last read of *obj_len* bytes from socket containing the whole content of *obj_data*.

Here's the code of my readLine function that works just with 1) and 2) types of messages :

```
char * readLine(int fd){
    char * buf=NULL; //here i store the content 
    char * tmp=calloc(CHUNK,sizeof(char));
    if(!tmp)
        return NULL;
    if(!buf)
        return NULL;
    buf[0]='\0';
    size_t byte_read=-1; 
    int len=0;
    do{ 
        bzero(tmp,CHUNK); //reset tmp for read
        byte_read=read(fd,(void *)tmp,CHUNK);
        if(byte_read==-1){
            perror("read");
            if(tmp)free(tmp);
            if(buf)free(buf);
            return NULL;
        }
        len=len+byte_read; //update the len of message
        buf=realloc(buf,len+1);
        if(!buf){
            perror("realloc");
            if(tmp)free(tmp);
            return NULL;
        }
        buf=strncat(buf,tmp,byte_read);//append each call of read
        if(byte_read>0 && buf[byte_read-1]=='\n')
        //the last byte read is  the special character
            break;
    }   
    while(byte_read!=0);
    if(byte_read==0)
        //read error SIGPIPE
    if(tmp)free(tmp);
    return buf;
    }
```

What should i do in your opinion for implement the function that read messages formatted like 2),3) and 1) from socket ?

Comment: `SOCK_STREAM` or `SOCK_DGRAM`?

Comment: It is SOCK_STREAM.

Comment: Are `command_name`, `object_name` and `object_len` space-separated? Is `object_len` given as an ASCII number?

Comment: yes they are space separated, and object_len is an ASCII number.
A realistic example of query of type 1) is :
    STORE objectNumberOne 10 \n helloWorld

Comment: OT: regarding statements like: `if(buf)free(buf);`  The function: `free()` properly handles a parameter than contains NULL, so no need to check for NULL in your code

Comment: OT: regarding: `buf=realloc(buf,len+1);`   the function: `realloc()` can fail.  When it fails, this code will result in the original pointer to allocated memory being overwritten, This results in an unrecoverable memory leak.   When calling `realloc()`, always assign the returned value to a 'temp' variable, then check (!=NULL) the 'temp' variable and if not NULL, then assign to the target variable.

Comment: regarding; `byte_read=read(fd,(void *)tmp,CHUNK);`  1) the code fails to check for `byte_read` being 0.  2) the number of bytes read can be less than `CHUNK`

Comment: regarding: `char * readLine(int fd){
    char * buf=NULL; //here i store the content 
    char * tmp=calloc(CHUNK,sizeof(char));
    if(!tmp)
        return NULL;
    if(!buf)
        return NULL;`  the `if(!buf)` will always be 'true', so the function will always perform the `return NULL;` statement.   Suggest removing the `if(!buf) return NULL;` code block

Comment: in function: `readLine()` about the seventh statement is; `buf[0]='\0';`  However, 'buf' still contains NULL,, so this will try to write '\0' to address 0.   This 'should' result in a 'seg fault event'  AND since 'buf' does not point to any memory owned by the application, the result is undefined behavior.   Of course, you might not see that problem because the prior `if()` code block has already exited the function

Comment: in function: `readLine()`, this statement: `buf=strncat(buf,tmp,byte_read);` will not work as expected because the first byte in `buf[]`, on the first loop iteration, has not been set to '\0'.

Comment: OT: regarding: `char * tmp=calloc(CHUNK,sizeof(char));
    if(!tmp)
        return NULL;`   this fails to notify the user that a failure occurred.  Suggest `char * tmp=calloc(CHUNK,sizeof(char));
    if(!tmp) { perror( "calloc failed" ); return NULL; }`

Comment: OT:  regarding: `byte_read=read(fd,(void *)tmp,CHUNK);`  there is no need to cast the pointer to `tmp`

Comment: regarding; `if(byte_read>0 && buf[byte_read-1]=='\n')`   the contents of 'buf[]' (after the first iteration, will contain more bytes than 'byte_read'.  so a '\n' will not be seen.  Suggest using: `if( byte_read>0 &&  strcspn( buf, "\n" ) )`

Comment: in function: readLine(), regarding: `if(byte_read==0)
        //read error SIGPIPE`   this does NOT mean a read error occurred nor that a `SIGPIPE` signal was sent.  What it does mean is the sender closed the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a different approach. First read a line, then determine what kind of message it is and only after that decide whether this is the end or you need to read up more bytes.

So lets start from reading a line:

```
int socket_readline(int fd, char *buf, size_t *inout_size)
{   
    char c = 0;
    size_t capacity = *inout_size;
    *inout_size = 0;

    while(c != '\n') {
        int rc = read(fd, &c, 1);

        if (rc != 1) return -1;

        buf[*inout_size] = c;
        *inout_size += 1;

        if (capacity - *inout_size == 0) return -1;
    }

    buf[*inout_size] = '\0';

    return 0;
}
```

This routine returns `0` on success and `-1` otherwise.

In a successful case the buffer is `NUL`-terminated and `inout_size` will be the length of the string in the buffer (excluding `NUL`-terminating byte). In case of error you should check `inout_size` value. in case of an overflow (line too long) it will be equal to the size of the buffer given (input buffer will not be `NUL`-terminated!), and for the read error it will contain how many bytes were read before an error occured.

Now once we have a read lining routine we can use it to parse incoming lines:

```
int rc;
size_t size;
char buf[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];

int object_len;
char command_name[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH], object_name[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];

do {
    size = sizeof(buf);
    rc = socket_readline(fd, buf, &size);
    if (rc == 0) {
        int tokens_matched = sscanf(buf, "%s %s %d \n", command_name, object_name, &object_len);

        switch(tokens_matched) {
            case 1:
                printf("This is a command: %s\n", command_name);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("This is a command: %s with object name: %s\n", command_name, object_name);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("This is a command: %s with object name: %s of length %d\n", command_name, object_name, object_len);
                printf("TODO read up remaining: %d bytes\n", object_len);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Error unable to match command format\n");
                break;
        }

    } else if (size == sizeof(buf)) {
        printf("Overflow! Bytes read: %lu. \n", size);
        // TODO How to handle overflows?
    } else {
        printf("Read error must have occured. Read %lu bytes.\n", size);
    }

} while (rc == 0 || size == sizeof(buf));
```

Comment: Thanks for comment, that's probably works. 
I have just a question : How could i do that without read one byte at time before the first occurence of \n ?

Comment: You can peek into socket's buffer by using SO_PEEK_OFF flag without actually removing the data from the buffer. See [socket manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages//man7/socket.7.html) for more details. (Search for SO_PEEK_OFF)

Comment: Then you could peek into beginning of an internal buffer and e.g. read 512 bytes, check if there is a newline and only after that use `read` to fetch as many bytes as required (till the \'n' occurence).

Comment: If you want to use options for each call then it will be easier to use `recv` instead of `read`.

Comment: the use of this flag with the use of MSG_PEEK in the recv function is what i was searching for.